# SQL Server select gets blocked when using ADO

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

I have a very old Delphi app that connects to SQL Server 2008 with ADO that always performed very well. In the last 5 days the app started to hung when querying data using an standard SELECT w/joins, causing a timeout in the application.

The problem is this: if I execute the same query in SSMS the query runs just fine (no wait, no hung).

Nothing has changed in the app, in the code, or in the servers (except the latest fixes from Windows Update).

I tried this:

- If I regenerate the indexes for all tables used in the SELECT, the app starts to work again (i.e. the query does not block) an minutes later it begins to block again.
- I checked sp_lock and the are no exclusive locks on the tables (Only S, IS and Sch-S locks).
- I tried setting the ADO cursors to READ-ONLY. This improved the performance but the query will blocks from time to time.

Comment: i think your application and SSMS are using different transactions mode

Comment: SSMS doesn't use ADO, so the comparison between the two doesn't mean anything. I don't see what we can do to help here; we don't have access to the database, tables, or SQL in order to troubleshoot the problem, and there's no Delphi involved. (ADO isn't Delphi, but is an MS product.)

Comment: Basic fault-finding logic should dictate that if the program hasn't changed (i.e. the same executable) then the problem must be environmental. Something else MUST have changed. Another app has been installed that modifies the DB Schema, or installs updated files, a server patch, client workstation update, the list goes on.

Comment: I tried changing the query and I realized it was something to do with the ORDER BY statement. If I remove it the query runs fast. I checked with Query Analyzer and I have all required index. However, I don't have the required statistics. Are they required?

Comment: Is it a stored proc that is executed? I assume not, since your post implies you SELECT in code, however I've had similar behaviour caused by parameter sniffing

Comment: It's not a stored procedure. I'll read about parameter sniffing. Thanks!